# Is there non-trivial multipartite entanglement not witnessed by the spectra of reduced states?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

A lot of analysis of multipartite entanglement is based on examining the spectra of various reduced states.  (E.g. area laws.)  Of course one generally needs not just the $N$ local states of each system, but also the $N$-choose-$2$ two-system reduced states, the $N$-choose-$3$ three-system reduced states, and so on.  In the simplest case, the entanglement properties of a pure bipartite state are completely determined by the spectrum of its reduced state on one system.

Is there a notion of multipartite entanglement that cannot be quantified in this way?  In other words, can one find two states of $N$ systems that have the same set of spectra for their $N!-1$ different reduced states, yet are (say) not incontrovertible under stochastic local operations and classical communication (SLOCC) or, equivalently, cannot be used for the same quantum information processing tasks?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as it turns out there are distinct types of multipartite entanglement not witnessed by the spectra of reduced states.  The simplest example is probably the one from Bennett et al., "Exact and asymptotic measures of multipartite pure-state entanglement", Phys. Rev. A 63, 012307 (2000).  For the case of three 4-dimensional systems, consider the states "3EPR" and "2GHZ".

[image]

(This is from their figure 3.) The former is just three EPR pairs with each party holding one half of two pairs.  The second is two GHZ states, each shared symmetrically between the three parties.   In this cases the spectra for all reduced states are identical, but the global states are very different and cannot be inter-converted through local operations.  To see this, note that tracing out one party leaves and entangled reduced state for the other two parties in the case of 3EPR, but a separable reduced state in the case of 2GHZ.